# Faster to do multiple sequential Joins in MySql vs one batch join?

Tags: mysql, join

I have sort of pushed the limit with `Joins` trying to `concatenate` a description field with various related `Look-Up Table` values. For instance:

This is Record 1 Description Field

**Hobbies**: Basketball, Hard Rock

**Favorite Foods**: Indian, French

**Social Sites**: Facebook, Twitter

I set up a `Select` with `Left Joins` to go gather the related data. I didn't bother posting it here because the question seems 'higher level', I can do so if required.

In any event I ran into the limit of 61 Joins in a single select statement which tells you how much is being queried and joined. My main table is ~2 million records, each of the others is anywhere from 50k to 1M records.

Naturally, this is taking a long time.

So my question is would I be better served to do this sequentially? To forestall any objection here, yes I could test it but it would require a massive amount of work to strip this into dozens of sequential selects and I want to make sure I am on the right path before testing that solution.

So in simple terms is there a performance gain in turning a query like this:

```
Select Concat(T.Description,L1.Name,..,LN.Name) from Table T
LEFT Join LUT1 L1
On T.ID=L1.TableID
...
LEFT Join LUTN LN
On T.ID=LN.TableID
```

into a series of joins where I store each stage for the next:

```
Insert into Temp (ID,NewDescription)
Select T.ID,Concat(T.Description,L1.Name) from Table T
LEFT Join LUT1 L1
On T.ID=L1.TableID
```

and then for each of the other `LUT`s

```
Update Temp set Desricption =
Select Concat(T.Description,L.Name) from Temp T
LEFT Join LUTN LN
On T.ID=LN.TableID
```

It seems 'logical' to me that doing multiple joins of a 2M record table to a single 100k record table would be more efficient than doing a join between a 2M record table and a dozen or more 100k record tables simultaneously, yet as mentioned above this is just a guess and confirming it without some confirmation from someone who knows this factually would be a pretty massive undertaking at this point. Hopefully, this question is within the bounds of acceptable questions on Stack.

Comment: I don't get it: `On T.ID=L1.TableID ... On T.ID=LN.TableID` - `L1` and `LN` refer to the same table (`LUT`). So as far as I see you are joining the same row again and again.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks for the catch, my bad, I fixed it in the description, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.. You have something that doesn't work (due to join limit), and something that might work. And you ask about performance difference? That doesn't make sence to me, since you first need something that works.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel My current join works. I just mentioned the limit to point out how much is in fact being joined. It just takes a lonnnng time. So it occurred to me that perhaps doing sequentialy might be the answer vs doing all the joins in one batch, but since I'm not sure of what is going on 'internally' I'm trying to find out if this is even a good direction to to since the only way to actually test is to pull this into dozens of serial join/inserts.

Comment: I'd guess the single huge query to be still faster. But I would run a test to verify it. You don't need to use all tables for the test. Compare the performance with say 5 tables. When you've done that, post the benchmark result as an answer here.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel 5 Tables won't really give me any insight as it is apples to oranges. Right now I'm going over  to see if I can add any indexes in my selects to improve performance. At some point I will test this out with ALL the tables as my gut tells me separate is better; I'm joining a 1m table 18 times or so to 100k tables into one final join and that seems to me to be exponentially worse than doing it sequentially. I will report back if adding indexes helps, and when I have some free time will tear this apart into sequential join/updates and benchmark it here for future reference for all.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Indexes helped, what helped too was removing the `Description` in the `Select` and just doing a `Concat` afterwards. Now that I optimized to a degree I'll report back ASAP on Sequential vs All.